# Deploying a scikit learn pipeline on IBM DSX

Tags: data-science-experience

How to deploy a trained scikit learn pipeline on IBM Data science experience? Can I do that from a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Please provide much more detail on your system/needs. In short, yes you can, but you'll need to configure a jupyter notebook server on your remote machine/cluster.

Comment: I am creating a Jupyter notebook on DSX, wouldn't that work?

Comment: please explain what you mean by deploy here, DSX notebook enviornment do have scikit module by default installed which you can use in your python code so please elaborate what you want to do with some code snippet?

Comment: I want to deploy a trained pipeline in Bluemix to get REST APIs corresponding to train and score/predict steps.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment of Scikit Learn Pipeline will be available in Watson Machine Learning. Today it is in close beta and only support deployment of Spark ML pipelines but we are adding support for Scikit Learn before summer.

More information here: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/PredictiveModeling/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I was at IBM DevConnect Hyderabad 2017, where I learned for the first time using Python Jupyter notebooks on DSX, that are by default available as a standard mode of using Python in IBM DSX platform.

By default, all notebooks come pre-installed with the common 20+ libraries necessary for data science experiments like scikit-learn, numpy,matplotlib, pandas etc. You can go to notebook info and check environment to get the full list of modules installed and versions.

You can try some of the samples from Github here to get started: github.com/IBMDevConnect17/DSX_HandsON

There is lot of learning available here with 4 courses here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-1611data-science-fundamentals-learning-path-bdu-trs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Find here a tutorial to deploy Scikit Learn pipelines to Watson Machine Learning(WML): https://datascience.ibm.com/exchange/public/entry/view/acba02c8efecc5218b1d65ba9b8a5bbb

WML supports deployment of Scikit-Learn v0.17, find more information here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/PredictiveModeling/pm_service_supported_frameworks.html#supported-machine-learning-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages by using the `!pip` command with user setting.

For example.

```
!pip install --user --upgrade sklearn
```